# C# Datagridview resize programmatically

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview that is populated and added to the winform programmatically.

The number of columns within the gridview can vary greatly, so I want to change the size of the actual Gridview width to fit the number of columns.

Could anybody suggest how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand it, but can't you just modify the width property of the grid each time you add a column?

```
DatagridView1.Width += 100; //estimated width of the column
```

EDIT:
Ok, so you add the columns binding it to a datasource. But later, you con do something like:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in DataGridView1.Columns)
{
                    //do things
}
```

Other solution could be redraw you form, and put the grid inside a panel, and set the dock property of the grid to Fill. The grid will use all the space available, and if more is needed, then will show scroll bars.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response, please see my response above.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi,  After a little further reading, I have found the method: datagridview.columns.getcolumnswidth that returns an integer value of total column width in pixels.  I then use that value to set the DGV width.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jonathan said, you can set the [FillWeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.fillweight.aspx) property for each column if you want it to be resized automatically:

```
buttonTest.Width = 80; //this is not resizable because we might have rendering problems
buttonTest.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

DescriptionColumn.FillWeight = 40; //for a text column, we can set it to be resized
```

Comment: The data isn't really added a column at a time, it is simply bound to a Datatable and I would like then to be able to tell the DG to adjust it's width to the last column.  Is that possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Does the ColumnAdded event fire? Because if it does, you can check the number of columns and make the size changes then (as in Jonathan's edit)

Comment: I'll have a check on that on Monday when I get back to the office.  Will let you know the outcome.  Thanks.